# How to make slideshare iframe responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

I have added slideshare iframe with presentation to my [page](http://bookofrakostenlosspielen.org/10-regeln-online-glucksspiels/)

Code: `<iframe src="//www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/key/HQoiz6GR1oLe1n" width="860" height="600" frameborder="600" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="border:1px solid #CCC; border-width:1px; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 100%;" allowfullscreen> </iframe>`
But when I open page at mobile phone there appear black area around presentation:
[screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJFtl.png)

I know that it happens because of style height="600", but when I remove it presentation becames small. How to remove this black areas around presentation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure *responsible* is a typo, unless you really ment it, in which case I suggest giving it important tasks?

Comment: Thanks, its Friday

Answer (score 1):

With some CSS it’s very easy to make slideshare embeds that scale the height in relation to the actual width.
You need to add an outer , with 0 height, and 100% width, and a padding-bottom as percentage of the aspect ratio (eg 9 / 16 = 56.25%) with an extra padding of 38px for the slide navigation.

```
<div class="iframe-slideshare-16x9">    
    <iframe src="//www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/key/h1Fw1vmfv5uVlM" 
        frameborder="0" 
        marginwidth="0" 
        marginheight="0" 
        scrolling="no" 
        allowfullscreen> 
    </iframe>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.iframe-slideshare-16x9 {
    padding-bottom: calc(56.25% + 38px);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}

.iframe-slideshare-16x9 iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid #CCC; 
}
```

More on this, at my blog: https://nathan.gs/2018/01/07/responsive-slideshare-iframe/

Answer (score 0):

this is not issue with iframe as your iframe is working properly and it is responsive

the problem is images/slides in slideshare iframe are bit small in height and I believe you cant do anything about it

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `media query` to your css:

```
@media (max-width: 667px) {
   iframe {
     width: 280px;
   }
}
```

Feel free to tweak values as desired.